# Debugging dynamically added Javascript code

Tags: javascript, firebug, dynamic

One of the programmers I worked with has something similar in code:

```
 var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
 var e = document.createElement("script");
 e.type = "text/javascript";
 var b = "function moo() { alert('hello'); }";
 e.appendChild(document.createTextNode(b));
 head.appendChild(e);
 moo();
```

This is all good and dandy, but I would like to step into moo(), and firebug just can't do that. I know I can rip the whole thing apart, but I reallllly don't want to touch it and his code works :)

Any ideas how I can debug this with Firebug?

Cheers

Comment: Just to save others the trouble: Chrome's DevTools don't magically handle it, either.

Comment: FWIW: I'd say the difficulty debugging it is an excellent argument in favor of refactoring it out. You're effectively doing an `eval` there (in a general sense), and there's nearly always a better way to approach it.

Comment: Any particular reason why the code is structured like this? It seems to me that if you already have the code being injected into the DOM, why not just declare it, use `new Function("...")` or eval it?

Comment: @Sean: There's a substantial scope/context difference between what he's doing and `eval`. If he's going to refactor it, I'd push for avoiding the `eval`-like-ness entirely. :-)

Comment: @Sean Kinsey: it's likely that this is a simplified example for the sake of the question, as is usually the case on Stack Overflow.  Also, I think the same problem would still exist with `eval` or `new Function()`.

Comment: @T.J Actually, the way the example is made, there is no difference in scope :)
I'm not advocating eval (There are few valid reasons for using it), but it is a better approach than what hes got right now.

Comment: @Andy I agree, which is why my first suggestion was to just declare it  ;) But I'm guessing there is a reason why this is not done in the first place..

Comment: Thanks for the ideas; true, it's a stripped down example I made to figure out how to make Firebug step in. Eval doesn't make life easier, same with new Function().

Answer (score 2):

[I drew a picture](http://skitch.com/olleolleolle/ddaem/test-of-http-stackoverflow.com-questions-2797671-debugging-dynamically-added-javascript-code), using Safari and its script debugger.

I prolonged your colleague's code to have some lines to step through.

```
var b = "function moo() { var a=10; a +=1; a+=10; alert(a); }";
```

See the picture for clearer explanation.

Comment: The picture shows that Safari's debugger DOES manage to step into the dynamically created function. I haven't verified that it works myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a `debugger;` statement in there. Firebug should recognize that, and let you step in.

Comment: tried; no go. I can breakpoint on the call to moo(), but cannot step in.

Answer (score 0):

IMO add a try-catch block:

```
 try{ 
      alert(\"hello!\") ; 
 } catch(e) { 
      console.log(e) ; 
 }
```

in order to get the error messages for any runtime errors. 
If I understand it correctly the problem here is that you are adding the above code branch at a `later stage` to an `earlier stage` (in terms of parsing chronology). Firebug will already have gone through the part you are changing and thus will not recognize the code.

Comment: The OP (original poster) said the code IS working, so no errors are supposedly there to see. It's true the OP didn't say WHY he wants to step into the code, so I'll assume it's either self-education or perhaps correctness verification of the code thats going on.

Comment: The OP said *Any ideas how I can debug this with Firebug?* Why do you assume he wants to debug working code?